# URL call in jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

When i click a button jquery has to get some content and has to call an URL **salesplanvalidation.jsp** with a parameter **salespersonid**
The code i used is as follows,

```
    $("#submit").click(function(){
                var spid=$('#heading').text();
                alert('salesplanvalidation.jsp?salespersonid='+spid);
    });
```

I specified the url in alert message that i want to call. If i use window.open() method it is loading into another tab instead of same page and can i get salespersonid value
as **request.getParameter("salespersonid");** in **salespersonvalidation.jsp** page?? or any other way to follow??

Comment: Do you want to know how to open a URL into the same page or call an ajax request ? What is the question ?

Comment: What does `alert(spid)` give you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to send and get some data from a server page. For that, you need ajax :

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var spid = $('#heading').text();
    $.get('salesplanvalidation.jsp',{salespersonid : spid},function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var spid=$('#heading').text();
  window.location.href = 'salesplanvalidation.jsp?salespersonid='+spid;
});
```

Will open your new_url into the same page

Comment: yes.. but while getting the value on salespersonvalidation.jsp as request.getPerameter("salespersonid"); it is returning null